# Super expression must either be null or a function, react native 0.26.3

Tags: ios, react-native

I am a newbie in react native.
I have one similar problem in different projects. When I try to compile my project, I see this problem. Why this error is appear?
P.S. I am learning react-native by tutorials like a appcoda.com

[Picture of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/997wh.png)

Featured.js

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');

var{
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Component
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  description:{
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
class  Featured extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Text style = {styles.description}>
        Featured tab
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = Featured;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your import statement as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. One question - how can I change my export statement to take access to other files? (I'm creating tab navigation) Can you give some links?

Comment: I am not clear on the question. Can you give an example what you want to achieve

Comment: I'm using a TabBarIOS component, I included tab                                           var Featured = require('./Featured'); but it still not appeared

Comment: change last line of Feature.js as "export default Featured;" and use it as "import Featured from './Featured';"